# Regex can't get the 3rd variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess

My regex code works well with second variable, the ([^&]+)(&.*) which is after `myvar=` , but i can't get the 3rd, which is after `foo=` (same as 2nd).

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?myvar=([^&]+)(&.*)?&foo=([^&]+)(&.*) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /site/myvar/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]
```

That outputs the url as follows:

```
http://localhost/site/myvar/15//
```

So how to output the 3rd variable between the last 2 backslashes?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Isn't it rather an .htaccess problem?

Comment: I didn't know the captures would carry across from the `Cond` to the `Rule`. Is this definitely the case?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: groups in the Cond are preceded by percent (%N where N is the group number). This only applies to the last Cond with a group. Groups in Rule are preceded by dollar ($N where N is the group number). http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the fourth capture, not the third. The third one is `(&.*)` even if that is empty. To determine the number, you simply count opening parentheses from left to right.